# Plug In Design for .NET App

Tags: .net, plugins, interface-design

I’m looking at rewriting a portion of our application in C# (currently legacy VB6 code). The module I am starting with is responsible for importing data from a variety of systems into our database.  About 5-6 times a year, a new client asks us to write a new import for the system that they use. Presently, this requires us to release a new version of our software for each new import option we add to the application.

One of the goals of the rewrite is to make the application support plug-ins. Every new import can become a separate assembly which the host application will recognize and allow the end user to interact with.  This will hopefully simplify life to some degree as we can simply drop a new assembly into the directory and have it be recognized and used by the main (host) application.

One of the items I am struggling with relates to the differences between the import options we currently support. In some cases we actually let the user point to a directory and read all of the files within the directory into our system. In other cases we allow them to point to a single file and import its contents. Additionally, some imports have a date range restriction that the user applies while others do not.

My question is, how can I design the application in a manner that allows for some flexibility among the imports we build and support while at the same time implementing a common interface that will allow the host application to easily recognize the plug-ins and the options that each one exposes to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you take a look at the Managed Add-In Framework that shipped with .NET 3.5. The [Add-In team](http://blogs.msdn.com/clraddins/) has posted some samples and tools at [CodePlex site](http://www.codeplex.com/clraddins) as well..

Answer (score 1):

.Net 3.5 has the system.Addin namespace.

This thread also has some good information for older versions of the framework:
h[ttp://forums.devshed.com/net-development-87/system-plugin-532149.html](http://forums.devshed.com/net-development-87/system-plugin-532149.html)

Answer (score 1):

for the theory take a look at the [plugin pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/plugin.html) in martin fowlers Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture

for an interesting example take a look at this tutorial: [Plugin Architecture using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/c__plugin_architecture.aspx)